# How to Handle CheckBox controls in MVC

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I want to handle check box event in MVC...I have design a view now I need to write a condition that if check box is checked then only following below controlls will show.Can any one help me.

[image]

Comment: https://blog.platformular.com/2012/03/13/dynamic-form-in-asp-net-mvc-jquery/

Comment: I don't think the other user's comment really applies here unless you need the ability to add a dynamic amount of check-boxes and fields.

Comment: Assuming you only have a set number of Medicare/health insurance options it's probably easiest to toggle their view with java-script/JQuery/some other front-end language.  Can you please post the HTML that is generated from that view and what front-end language(s) you're using?  After that you may want to adjust the tags to reflect those as well.